# PHP PDO MySql - Insert with an occasionally Undefined Variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

A simplified example of a much more complex issue...
A variable is sometimes defined and sometimes isn't.  WITHOUT checking if the variable is empty, is there a way to execute the insert statement without the Query breaking?

```
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO employment (user_id, start_date, end_date) VALUES (:user_id, :start_date, :end_date) ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':start_date', $work->start_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':end_date', $work->end_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Sometimes `$work->end_date` may be non-existent.

Why "WITHOUT checking if variable is empty"?  The primary foundation of the site changed and there would be a ton of variable checking.  Yes, I know that shouldn't be but it is the problem I inherited.

Comment: Can you not just pass a `NULL` value for the `_STR` type? What kind of problem/errormsg do you get with that?

Comment: Deleting this question.  ERROR in the database schema made the query not work.  PDO will still accept a non-existent variable and will default to NULL. Thus there is no need for this question.

Comment: INSERT IGNORE? but this would require modifying insert statements. Although doing a search and replace on $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO ... would be easy, and dangerous .. hah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always try to write a wrapper to `bindParam` which would check your if you variable is defined. If it is then it goes ahead and bindParam otherwise it skips it.

Call it like

`bindSafeParam(&$stmt, ':start_date', $work->start_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Answer (score 0):

Have a default value if $work->end_date does not exist?

Something like this:

```
$end_date = empty($work->end_date)? 0 : $work->end_date
$stmt->bindParam(':end_date', $work->end_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: PLEASE SEE ABOVE:  The questions states "WITHOUT checking if variable is empty".  Thanks for the answer but not what I am looking for.